# Missing Add, Edit and delete functionality from default power app with Sql

Tags: powerapps, powerapps-collection, powerapps-selected-items

While creating a default power app with sql, I am facing some issue mention below-
As we create a default power app with sql server then add, edit and delete functionality is not present in the app. I can add delete and edit the records from the database but I am not able to do it from UI.

Comment: Could you share a screenshot?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that you are looking for a Dashboard, view, Edit/New form that comes in PowerApps whenever you connect using SharePoint Connector.
If that is true, than you can create a PowerApp with SharePoint connector,so that you will have those screens that you are looking for. Than create another PowerApp with SQL connector and copy paste those three screens from previous app to current App and Change the connection.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.
As you have suggested I have created an app with excel and then create another PowerApps with SQL connector and copy paste those three screens from the previous app to the current App but while changing the connection of that app I am facing an issue of one or more implicitly share connections.
Is this functionality is achievable in the premier version only?

Comment: Yes, connecting to SQL connector is a premium connector.